# SQL insert into select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

I have 2 tables.

`Attendance` table with 2 columns and `Records` table with 1 column

```
+----------------------+
|       Attendance     |
+----------------------+
| EmployeeID   | Hours |
+----------------------+ 

+--------------+
|   Records    |
+--------------+
| EmployeeID   |
+--------------+
|     1        |
|     2        |
|     3        |
+--------------+
```

I want a query that will insert all `employeeID` from `Records` table into `EmployeeID` in the `Attendance` table with a value of 8 in `Hours` column.

Like this:

```
+----------------------+
|       Attendance     |
+----------------------+
| EmployeeID   | Hours |
|----------------------|
|      1       |   8   |
|      2       |   8   |
|      3       |   8   |
+----------------------+
```

I can't understand the code that I searched so I end up asking :)

By the way, I'm using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently, I have made a query like that you want.

```
INSERT INTO Attendence (EmployeeID, Hours) 
    SELECT EmployeeID, 8 
    FROM Records 
    WHERE EmployeeID > 0
```

`WHERE` condition is for `SELECT`, not for `INSERT INTO`. This query will copy all `EmployeeID`'s to `Attendence` table where `EmployeeID` is greater than `0`.

```
SELECT EmployeeID, 8 FROM Records
```

will return something like

```
(1,8),(2,8),(3,8)
```

Comment: I don't understand the WHERE 1. I got an error "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'SET'". But if I remove WHERE 1, I got no problem. Thanks to you anyway.

Comment: `WHERE 1` means that there is no specific condition for the `SELECT`ed rows. Of course you can delete it.

Comment: Im using MSSQL. I guess WHERE 1 is only on mySql? Correct me if i'm wrong. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
INSERT INTO Attendance (EmployeeID, Hours) 
    SELECT EmployeeID, 8 FROM Records;
```